# Which of these two sentences is correct ("processes" vs. "process")?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number, american-english, nouns

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

> Read more about the processes behind my projects.

...or...

> Read more about the process behind my projects.

The one on top looks right technically, but the one on bottom sounds better to me.

Comment: What's the context?  What do you mean by process/processes?

Comment: I think the real question is one you have to answer yourself: are there multiple **processes** behind your projects, or is there one unifying **process** behind *all* of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. They denote different things, depending on...whether or not there are multiple processes involved.

Answer (score 0):

If there's one, overarching process you use for all of your projects, say "process." If you use a different process for different types of projects, say "processes."

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of context and semantics. Do you use a single process to perform all of your projects? Then the second is correct.

Differing processes to perform each task would indicate that the first is correct.